# SharedPreferences are being restored as defaults in onResume instead of the saved SharedPreferences values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity, onresume

I have a PreferenceActivity P that stores values to SharedPreferences.  This is working--I am able to make selections from the lists and the summary values are displayed correctly.

The problem is when I attempt to access the SharedPreference values within Activity A.   The *default* values are loaded instead of the stored values.  Only *after* I access the PreferenceActivity from Activity A do the up-to-date SharedPreference values become available to Activity A.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this?  Is there any option to using PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences?

Here is the bulk of the PreferenceActivity code (I omitted the onSharedPreferenceChanged listener for brevity):

```
public class P extends PreferenceActivity { 
public static String KEY_PREF_show_watch_areas, KEY_PREF_time_format, KEY_PREF_date_format;
String PREF_show_watch_areas, PREF_time_format, PREF_date_format;
static SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
Preference pref_show_watch_areas=null;
ListPreference pref_time_format=null, pref_date_format=null;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( getApplicationContext() );
    KEY_PREF_show_watch_areas = getString(R.string.key_pref_show_watch_areas);
    KEY_PREF_time_format = getString(R.string.key_pref_time_format);
    KEY_PREF_date_format = getString(R.string.key_pref_date_format);
    PREF_show_watch_areas = getString(R.string.pref_show_watch_areas);
    PREF_time_format = getString(R.string.pref_time_format);
    PREF_date_format = getString(R.string.pref_date_format);

//Load up the preference items (from XML)  
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    //DATE pref
    pref_date_format = (ListPreference) findPreference(KEY_PREF_date_format); //Set summary to user selected value
    pref_date_format.setSummary(pref_date_format.getEntry() ); 

    //TIME pref
    pref_time_format = (ListPreference) findPreference(KEY_PREF_time_format); //Set summary to show user selected value
    pref_time_format.setSummary(pref_time_format.getEntry()); 

    }

 }  // [END P]
```

Here is the onResume in Activity A:

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

   SharedPreferences sharedPrefsResume = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext() );
   dateFormatPref = sharedPrefsResume.getString(P.KEY_PREF_date_format, "d-MMM-yy");
   timeFormatPref = sharedPrefsResume.getString(P.KEY_PREF_time_format, "h");

 } // [END onResume]
```

Comment: Are you commiting your changes in any point? It's not enough to add them.

Comment: Are you loading defaults using PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues()?

Comment: @Clyde: I just tried using PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues() but it had no impact on the problem.

Comment: @EfEs: I added commits but this had no effect on the problem.  As I mentioned in the question, the preference values have been set in the PreferenceActivity.  But to get the values is currently requiring executing a startActivity(new Intent(this, P.class)).  I cannot figure out how to get the values that have been set without a visit to the PreferenceActivity.  I am not making any changes to the values while in the PreferenceActivity but as soon as I return to Activity A they are magically available instead of the default values.

Comment: Are they on the same package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered and resolved the problem.  I was trying to access the SharedPrefs values with uninitialized variables (e.g., P.KEY_PREF_date_format). That's the reason the default values were being returned. I've now moved the static variables to my MainActivity to ensure they are initialized.  Voila.  SharePreferences are working as expected now.